# Interpreting $R^2$ when using a single categorical variable

Tags: regression, categorical-data, regression-coefficients

My understanding of $R^2$ is that it represents three things:

1. The linear relationship between variables in a regression.
2. The amount of variability explained by a regression.
3. A proxy for the efficacy of a model.

Given a simple linear regression with a single categorical variable, it makes sense for reason 1 that $R^2$ will be around zero; after all, there's no linear relationship. A scatter plot will just show points that fall along two vertical lines.

[image]

```
## 
## Call:
## lm(formula = math_test_pct_prof_midpt ~ econ_disadvantaged, data = data_munged)
## 
## Residuals:
##     Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
## -46.521 -19.521  -4.021  23.251  58.251 
## 
## Coefficients:
##                       Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
## (Intercept)           48.52123    0.08699  557.77   <2e-16 ***
## econ_disadvantagedYes -7.27224    0.24182  -30.07   <2e-16 ***
## ---
## Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
## 
## Residual standard error: 24.87 on 93877 degrees of freedom
## Multiple R-squared:  0.009542,   Adjusted R-squared:  0.009531 
## F-statistic: 904.4 on 1 and 93877 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

But then, does that also mean that the regression in question isn't reliable following reason 2? Put another way, do these coefficient estimates have any grounds for legitimacy?

---

***Edit: Added a box/violin plot and geom_jitter plot for context, and corrected the description of the scatter plot.***

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regression with a dichotomous categorical predictor is the same thing as a 2 independent samples t-test.  In this context, $R^2$ can be used as an effect size, though something like Cohen's $d$ is probably more appropriate.

There is indeed a correlation, $r_{\text{pb}}$ in this context...it is called the point-biserial correlation.  It is also the case that $R^2 = r_{\text{pb}}^2$.

Lastly, you do not obtain two vertical lines in the plot.  You obtain two sets of points that fall on 2 vertical lines (one above each of the locations for your dichotomous variable).  I would suggest using the `jitter(·)` function to add some visually useful noise into the plot.  Or better yet, you could plot parallel boxplots.  With these sets of points, each has a mean, and the regression slope is simply the difference between the group means.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm not entirely certain that I understand though, and I'd like to request some clarification.

You stated that for this type of regression, the "point-biserial correlation" is equivalent to R^2. Is this represented by the R^2 value in the regression summary above? And should I interpret it in the same fashion as I would R^2, with this model indicating almost non-existent correlation?

Comment: The point-biserial correlation squared is the same as $R^2$, the coefficient of determination.  But, if you wish to use the correlation as a metric of effect size, then it would be $\sqrt{0.009542} = 0.09768316$.  However, I would suggest using Cohen's $d$ effect size which is $d = \frac{-7.27224}{24.87} = -0.2924$ (which using Cohen's convention would be classified as a small effect size).

Comment: Is there any reason to prefer one effect size measurement over the other? I read over the Wikipedia page on effect size following your comment, and I'm rather overwhelmed by the variety presented.

Comment: The convention with 2 independent sample t-tests is to use the Cohen's $d$...so my suggestion would be to default to that.  There are times then you might want $r_\text{pb}$ or $R^2$, but they are much less common for this context.